# CompositeCollection doesn't propagate changes in underlying collections

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I have what I thought was an ideal scenario for a CompositeCollection, except it seems that changes **to the items of the** underlying collection do not appear in the CompositeCollection (or, at any rate, not in the control whose source is this CompositeCollection).

**EDIT 1**: both underlying collections are ObservableCollections.
**EDIT 2**: the new/updated item gets added, but the contents of that item are not reflected in the drop-down area of the combobox. Each item implements INotifyPropertyChanged.

Am I doing something wrong or is this not supported?

Here's what I have:

```
<ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding Products}">
   <ComboBox.Resources>
      <CollectionViewSource x:Key="CustomProductsSource" Source="{Binding CustomProducts}" />
   </ComboBox.Resources>
   <ComboBox.ItemsSource>
      <CompositeCollection>
          <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={x:Static local:Products.Standard}}" />
          <Separator/>
          <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource CustomProductsSource}}"/>
      </CompositeCollection>                                        
    </ComboBox.ItemsSource>                                     
</ComboBox>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it - the problem was (as it is most often is) an idiot programmer (that would be me).

It so happened that Item of the collection (individual Product class) had an overriden `ToString()` method returned the Name property of the Product instance. So, the combo box was showing what it was supposed to show, which is the name of the product, except it was doing it based on the `ToString()` method... BECAUSE I FORGOT TO CREATE A DATATEMPLATE for the ComboBox. No wonder then that changes to the Name were not reflected

Answer (score 0):

What type of collections are `Products.Standard` and `CustomProducts`? If they do not have change notification (do not implement [INotifyCollectionChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Collections.Specialized.INotifyCollectionChanged.aspx)), then `CompositeCollection` has no means to know that something changed.

[ObservableCollection<>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx) for example should work just fine in this scenario.

Comment: They are both ObservableCollections... hence the problem :/

Comment: Well, I even checked just in case, CompositeCollection works ok with ObservableCollections and shows updates. 
So ComboBox shows some items but does not update with new ones, right?
Can you post your code for `Products.Standard`, `CustomProducts` and how you update them?

Comment: I don't actually have the code for Products.Standard and CustomProducts - I simplified for question for the sake of brevity. Just to clarify, the item gets added, but the content of that item does not change in the drop-down list of the combobox

Comment: So you\`re saying that ComboBox shows new items right away, but if you change some properties of theese items - changes are not reflected? Hard to tell what you\`ve missed without code. If items implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, do they actually call PropertyChanged event in setter?